# How to configure a swipeGesture direction according to the orientation

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement different swipe directions depending on the orientation (swipe left for landscape mode and swipe up for portrait mode). It works except that the first one that the view is displayed in a new orientation, you must first make the swipe of the other orientation. Only 1 time.
Can you help me understand what's going on?

This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector (orientation(_:)))
        swipe.direction = [.up, .left]
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)


    }
    @objc func orientation (_ sender : UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            sender.direction.remove(.up)
            swipeLabel.text = "Swipe left to share"
            print("je suis landscape et left")
            sender.direction = .left
            shareScreenShot()

        }else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
            swipeLabel.text = "Swipe up to share"
            print("je suis portrait et up")
            sender.direction = .up
            shareScreenShot()

        }
```

Comment: Instead of requiring a swipe gesture to set the direction, why not use `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, which will be called when orientation changes, to do this?

Comment: Indeed, I turned to this solution. thank you.